# Does postgreSQL index multi-valued fields?

Tags: postgresql

For example, I store `interests` for Joe as `chemistry` and `classical-music` (as **two separate values**) , and you can query the table like `where interests in ('chemistry', 'biochem')` and it will use the index to efficiently find people such as Joe.

Does PostgreSQL have such a datatype that can index multiple values to allow advanced queries? What are the performance advantages for queriues? And what are the important **caveats**?

Comment: Why don't you normalize your design? Storing comma separated values is almost never a good idea.

Comment: I understand its bad in traditional DBs which dont index multiple values. But I just felt DBs must offer this feature. But I did update this question about caveats thanks to you :-)

Comment: The question is misleading/poorly worded. You're asking if it can index the values in a text field containing comma-separated values.

Comment: I think the caveat is that it's not a good design.  If you want to use a RDBMS, then I second other people recommendation to create a proper, relational schema to store the data. People have been working for decades to create very efficient ways to do this kind of querying (via a separate "interests" table). PostgreSQL is quite good at it.  Otherwise, I suggest you evaluate different storage engines.

Comment: @DondiMichaelStroma, corrected the poor wording

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use an array datatype, it can be indexed and the index can be used, check this topic: [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns)

A better datamodel might be a better idea, but that's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/hstore.html) datatype for this. You would only store keys, not values. A hstore column can be indexed and testing for the presence of a key is really fast.

Something like:

```
create table person 
(
   person_id integer not null primary key,
   name text not null,
   interests hstore
);

insert into person (person_id, name, interests)
values 
(1, 'Joe', 'chemistry => NULL, biochem => null'::hstore);
```

Then to find a person with a specific interest you can use:

```
select *
from person
where interests ? 'chemistry'
   or interests ? 'biochem';
```

It's a bit of a hack because the `hstore` datatype is intended to store key/value pairs and in this case you only need the keys.