# Efficiently query table with conditions including array column in PostgreSQL

Tags: performance, postgresql, indexing, query-optimization

Need to come up with a way to efficiently execute a query with and array and integer columns in the `WHERE` clause, ordered by a timestamp column.  Using PostgreSQL 9.2.

The query we need to execute is:

```
SELECT id 
from table 
where integer = <int_value> 
  and <text_value> = any (array_col) 
order by timestamp 
limit 1;
```

`int_value` is an integer value, and `text_value` is a 1 - 3 letter text value.

The table structure is like this:

```
    Column     |            Type             |       Modifiers
---------------+-----------------------------+------------------------
 id            | text                        | not null
 timestamp     | timestamp without time zone |
 array_col     | text[]                      |
 integer       | integer                     |
```

How should I design indexes / modify the query to make it as efficient as possible?

Thanks so much!  Let me know if more information is needed and I'll update ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PG can use indexes on array but you have to use array operators for that so instead of `<text_value> = any (array_col)` use `ARRAY[<text_value>]<@array_col` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4059785/2115135). You can use the command `SET enable_seqscan=false;` to force pg to use indexes if it's possible to see if the ones you created are valid. Unfortunately `GIN` index can't be created on integer column so you will have to create two diffrent indexes for those two columns.
See the execution plans here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/66a71/2

Comment: Ok, thanks. What about the order by?  How can I address that?

Comment: Oh, I missed that. In that case `index(integer,timestamp)` should be faster than two separate index on `(integer)` and `(timestamp)` but I'm afraid that's a bit above my level so I can't guarantee that so you should try it out.

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately GIN index can't be created on integer column so you will have to create two diffrent indexes for those two columns.

That's not entirely true, you can use [`btree_gin`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gin.html) or -[`btree_gist`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gist.html)

```
-- feel free to use GIN
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
CREATE INDEX ON table USING gist(id, array_col, timestamp);
VACUUM FULL ANALYZE table;
```

Now you can run the operation on the index itself

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id = ? AND array_col @> ?
ORDER BY timestamp;
```