# Search an array of records in a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have an array of records. The record is something like `(id, text_value)`

And I'd like to search such in a `WHERE` clause. I'd like to include rows which have a certain value within the array of records. However, the function `ANY`, for example, seems to take equality as a single value. For example:

```
WHERE 'one' = ANY('{one,two}'::text[])
```

Whereas, my clause would be `ANY(array_of_records)`. And the left hand side would therefore need to access a column in the record.

Is this possible in a WHERE clause, or should I use plpgsql to loop over the rows?

I'm also happy to use `json` or `jsonb` to do any array of records searching if that helps.

Comment: I am not sure if I get the correctly but what is the issue with `WHERE 'one' = ANY('{one,two}'::text[])` ?As this seems to be fine.

Comment: Yes, it is fine. But I'm using it with records, not strings.

Comment: **Is this possible in a WHERE clause** ... What were the results when you tried it?

Comment: I'm unable to try it, since the LHS of the ANY function takes a single value, whereas I'd need to, procedurally speaking, loop through the array of records and check the 'text_value' of each against each record looped

Comment: The array of records is created with array_agg() on values from a join table.

Comment: What's the structure of your "array of records"? Could you please provide some concrete DDL and/or examples?

Comment: The structure of the array is (integer, text).

Comment: `ANY` is neither function nor operator, but an SQL *construct*, btw. May seem like nitpicking, [but that can make a big difference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29245753/939860).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just unnest the array and join it to your table. I'm going to make some assumptions about your schema... This is the record you were referring to, from which you can create an array `r[]`:

```sql
CREATE TYPE r AS (
  id INT,
  text_value TEXT
);
```

This is the table that contains values which you want to search for in your array of records:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t(v) AS
VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ('d');
```

Now, simply join the two:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t
JOIN unnest(array[row(1, 'a')::r, row(2, 'b')::r]) u
ON t.v = u.text_value
```

This will yield

```
v  id  text_value
-----------------
a  1   a
b  2   b
```

Comment: Thanks, this is basically how I solved it. 
Previously, I made the array of records with `array_agg(select my_join.id, my_join.text_value)`. Now, I've done an additional array_agg which just has the `text_value`  which works fine with `ANY()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to create some filters before your query.

$tmp = array();

for (i=0; i < array.length; i++){
 if(condition)
   $tmp[] = array[i];
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM example WHERE id IN (".implode(',',$tmp).")";

Comment: Thanks, I'll try something like this if there isn't a less verbose solution. I'm thinking of an aggregate function that loops over the records and looks for a certain values in a certain column in the record. Would be nice if there were an inbuilt solution, however.