# Is there a way to select like with custom separator

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-like

I have postgresql table that looks like this:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id |        names        |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | foo|bar and biz|pop |
+----+---------------------+
```

I want to select row containing given name. Something like

```
SELECT "id" FROM "table" WHERE "names" LIKE '%foo%';
 id
-----
1
(1 row)
```

I want the query to return this row as well if I ask for `bar and biz` but return nothing if I ask from `bar`.

For now I'm adding pipe symbols to the beginning and the end of the line and ask `LIKE '%|bar and biz|%'`. Anyway, I wonder is there a way to find that row without additional pipes.

Is there a way to do such query in postgresql?

**UPD:** It seems like I explain my problem bad. Well, I want following:

```
SELECT "id" FROM "table" WHERE "names" LIKE '%bar and biz%';
 id
-----
1
(1 row)
```

and

```
SELECT "id" FROM "table" WHERE "names" LIKE '%bar%';
 id
-----
(0 rows)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, storing multiple values in a single column is a bad idea:

- SQL is not very good at string operations.
- Such operations cannot make use of indexes.
- You cannot use foreign key relationships to validate values.

Instead, you should be using a junction table.  Postgres also has other solutions for storing lists, such as arrays and JSON.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's bad design decisions.  One method using `like` is:

```
SELECT "id"
FROM "table"
WHERE '|' || "names" || '|' LIKE '%|bar|%';
```

Comment: To be honest this solution is mine and I've created this column just a moment ago. I tried to created something as simple as I can to keep aliases in table but you're right, the discussion here and your sql snippet point me that my idea was completely wrong. I better rewrite this to be array or something. Thank you for knowledge sharing.

Answer (score 2):

While stuck with your unfortunate design, convert to an array and use the `ANY` construct:

```
SELECT id
FROM   table
WHERE  'bar' = ANY (string_to_array(names, '|'));
```

About `ANY`, `@>`, arrays and indexes:

- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns/29245753#29245753)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the following?

```
where "names" = 'foo' or
      "names" LIKE 'foo|%' or 
      "names" LIKE '%|foo' or
      "names" LIKE '%|foo|%'
```

Comment: Seems like I explain my problem bad. Pls, check out update in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Since your column is already separated with '|' you could cast it to an array an use the contains to get your desired result

```
SELECT "id"
FROM "table"
WHERE string_to_array(names, '|')::varchar[] @> '{bar}'::varchar[];
```

Answer (score 0):

I just checked in my system and it is working fine for me. First of all i don't understand why you have double quotes in column name. It's not recommended.

My table schema

```
CREATE TABLE table (
  id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  names varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And to fetch data, i used this

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE names LIKE '%foo%' or names LIKE '%bar and biz%';
```

Update:-

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE names LIKE '%bar%';
```

[image]

Remove double quotes from coulmn names and table names.

Comment: Seems like I explain my problem bad. Pls, check out update in the question. Btw I use double quotes because I have camel-case named columns and postresql automatically converts everything to lowercase in case there are no double quotes around it.