# Which PHP ORM with built in array type (for PostgreSQL)?

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to use PostgreSQL as main RDB in my Symfony 3 based project. I plan to use PostgreSQL **array type** extensively (storing arrays, querying arrays), and possibly other PostgreSQL specific functionalities.

Which ORM has is best suited for it? I see that Doctrine 2 has 'array type', but it stores elements in text fields. I would like to use some existing ORM / extension for ORM, not create it by myself (like creating some mappings for Doctrine).

Query builder with support for array operators would be a big plus.

Answer (score 1):

From Doctrine 2.6 you can use the json_array type ( see http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#mapping-matrix ) and you can then query using the Native Query functionality.

There is also an open source Symfony Bundle which back ports this functionality https://github.com/boldtrn/JsonbBundle if need to be on an older version of Doctrine.

I know you specifically asked about the Postgres array type but storing as an array in the JSON type is very similar from my understanding. I would be interested to know if there are any downsides to this?

Comment: I want to use array type because then I can use dedicated indexes and operators to query( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns ). They are pretty good and could be often used instead of extra search engine like SOLR/ElasticSearch/Sphinx.

Comment: Yeah a lot of this can be done with the JSON type as well. I understand that the array type will have better performance in some cases but JSON type can be indexed and queried too. The Postgres Full text search can also be used with them. I'm not aware of an ORM with better support for Postgres