# How do I create an index on an array/rows?

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have an email with the tags 'inbox', 'unread', 'friend' and their tag id is 1,2,3. In my database I have something like

```
create email(emailID serial, header_data text, body text, tags int[])
```

I'd like to search my inbox for everything with tagid 2. The email I want will have the tags value as [1,2,3]. How do I create an index so this email is included? I'm using C# but I don't think that matters.

Comment: You should normalize your tables instead

Comment: http://www.databasesoup.com/2015/01/tag-all-things.html

Comment: This might be the answer you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan: IDK what retards upvoted you but it's literally [the worse method according to the benchmarks horse linked](http://www.databasesoup.com/2015/01/tag-all-things-part-2.html). People shouldn't leave comments when they don't know the consequences of their suggestions.

Comment: @acidzombie24 you sweet summer child. If performance was the only concern, you'd write everything in assembly.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan: Haha you got me there. IMO my layout is the most simple way and I always hated making a table just to link up a one to many relationship. However I don't think I should do it the way you suggest unless there's a good reason and because people typically do it that way isn't a good reason (people still use old version of software too)