# Can I index an (unnest) array?

Tags: postgresql

I want to write something like

```
create index on thread(unnest(tags));
```

But I get the error

> ERROR:  index expression cannot return a set

Basically I want to find all docs that have the tagid of 2 in them ([see my other question for details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43214583/34537)) and I'm assuming the below acts like a blob(I won't find [1,2] because 1 isn't in my query)

```
create index on thread(tags);
```

Comment: [Tip](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html): *Arrays are not sets; searching for specific array elements can be a sign of database misdesign. Consider using a separate table with a row for each item that would be an array element. This will be easier to search, and is likely to scale better for a large number of elements.*

Comment: @pozs: Another user linked me [to this](http://www.databasesoup.com/2015/01/tag-all-things.html) which shows what your suggesting has poor performance and text[] has better (however my tags has metadata so I can't use text[])

Answer (score 6):

Use the [GIN index type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/indexes-types.html):

```
CREATE INDEX ON thread USING gin (tags);
```

... and then query the table with the [`@>` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-array.html):

```
SELECT * FROM thread WHERE tags @> ARRAY[2];
```

Comment: Just a few questions. What happens if I don't write `USING gin`? From what I saw before gin seems to be a hash? What happens if I'm using an index/int does it use the int value instead?

Comment: @acidzombie: If you don't say `USING gin`, you get a `btree` instead, and the index will only be used by queries involving `=` / `<` / `>` comparisons. Internally, I think a GIN index is just a B-tree, but its keys are the array members rather than the arrays themselves. You can read more about the implementation in the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/gin-implementation.html).

Comment: Thanks nick this sounds perfect. I'm mostly nervous bc IDK what to expect. It looks like (from you and docs) the default btree must match the key/array exactly and this doc says it can use multiple index for one row. It sounds perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you know the exact value you are looking for, you can use smth like

```
create index on thread(tags @> '{2}');
```

and if you have higher version ([>=9.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-array.html)) of postgres, you can use `array_position`

**and answering your question:**
you can't use `unnest` as function for index