# Test ARRAY whether it contains ALL or NO elements of given ARRAY

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, operators, postgresql-13

Suppose we have an array:

```sql
ARRAY[1,2,3]
```

With the operator <@ I can query whether the left-operand is a sub-array of the right-operand:

```sql
ARRAY[1, 2] <@ ARRAY[1,2,3]
```

The above works greatly but now let's take the following case:

```sql
ARRAY[1, 2] <@ ARRAY[1,3,7]
```

In this case the above will return false as expected.

Do we have an operator which says the following:

- either the left array is contained by the right array
- or each of the elements in the left array IS NOT contained at all in the right array?

As of today I can easily come up with a solution involving the overlap operator but it is not really what I am looking for.
It complicated enormously my query and I would need to do some more complicated string machinery on the application side to build the query.

I am using PostgreSQL 13.

Comment: Is it all `integer` numbers like your examples suggest? `int4` ? Can there be NULL values as elements or NULL arrays? If so, how to deal with those? Are array elements always unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no **single operator** to check for both (either *contained* or *no overlap*).
Not in Postgres 13, not in any standard Postgres distribution.

But you can easily [**create your own operator**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createoperator.html). I chose the operator name `<@!&&` to be explicit and because it won't collide with any existing operator. Pick what you like, maybe something shorter since you are aiming for short code.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION f_array_contained_or_no_overlap(anyarray, anyarray)
  RETURNS boolean
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
'SELECT $1 <@ $2 OR NOT $1 && $2';

CREATE OPERATOR <@!&& (
  FUNCTION = f_array_contained_or_no_overlap
, LEFTARG  = anyarray
, RIGHTARG = anyarray
);
```

Then you can:

```sql
SELECT ARRAY[1,2] <@!&& ARRAY[1,2,7] AS contained     -- true
     , ARRAY[1,2] <@!&& ARRAY[4,5,6] AS no_overlap    -- true
     , ARRAY[1,2] <@!&& ARRAY[4,2,6] AS part_overlap; -- false
```

| contained | no_overlap | part_overlap |
| --- | --- | --- |
| t | t | f |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e90828fac276bc5c13cc7bb7a46d1f04)*

Achieves your declared goal of short, simple code.
Works for any array (any element type), but both operands must be compatible, of course.

**But ...**

Does not allow NULL elements, because the underlying [generic array operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE) don't either.

Cannot use any indexes. See:

- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns/29245753#29245753)

If you use the underlying function `f_array_contained_or_no_overlap(anyarray, anyarray)` instead of the operator directly, [Postgres should be able to inline it](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions), so that an applicable GIN index can still be used.

If it's all integer arrays, a faster implementation can probably be had using the additional module [`intarray`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html) (which does not have a built-in operator for that, either).

Answer (score 1):

You could phrase by checking for a sub-array match or zero overlap.

This is true, since the first array is a subarray of the second:

```sql
ARRAY[1,2] <@ ARRAY[1,2,3] OR NOT ARRAY[1,2] && ARRAY[1,2,3];
```

This is also true, since the first array is not a subarray but it also has zero overlap:

```sql
ARRAY[4,5] <@ ARRAY[1,2,3] OR NOT ARRAY[4,5] && ARRAY[1,2,3];
```