# Postgres UUID array index possible with ANY?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (
    id uuid NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    duplicate_ids uuid[] DEFAULT NULL,
);
```

And my query is:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 'some-uuid'=ANY(duplicate_ids)
```

Using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and trying lots of different indexes, I am unable to get the above to use an index.

Here's what I've tried (Postgres 12):

```
CREATE INDEX duplicate_ids_idx ON my_table USING GIN (duplicate_ids);
CREATE INDEX duplicate_ids_idx ON my_table USING GIN (duplicate_ids array_ops);
CREATE INDEX duplicate_ids_idx ON my_table USING BTREE (duplicate_ids);
CREATE INDEX duplicate_ids_idx ON my_table USING BTREE (duplicate_ids array_ops);
```

I've also ran `SET enable_seqscan TO off;` before these tests to enforce index usage.

Questions I've read:

- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns)

  - Doesn't seem to apply for single values
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125413/index-not-used-with-any-but-used-with-in

  - Seems to be talking about indexing multiple columns and using `IN`

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Try `where duplicate_ids && array['some_uuid']::uuid[]` or `where duplicate_ids @> array['some_uuid']::uuid[]`

Comment: Thank you very much! That works great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question was answered by @a_horse_with_no_name

The solution appears to be to use something like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE duplicate_ids && array['some_uuid']::uuid[]
```