# How, in PostgreSQL, can I iterate through table A, and use a column from table A as a limit for a join to table B to populate table C

Tags: postgresql, loops, database-cursor, greenplum

Working with Greenplum 6 (based on PostgreSQL 9.4.), I have these
sample tables:

Table `SAMPLE_A`:

```
| uniqueId | SampleSz |
| -------- | -------- |
| 1        | 25       |
| 2        | 50450    |
| 3        | 9        |
```

Table `SAMPLE_B`:

```
| IP       | uniqueId |
| -------- | -------- |
| 1.4.4.5  | (1,2,3)  |
| 2.5.6.7  | (2)      |
| 3.4.7.8  | (1,3)    |
```

I am trying to create a new table from the above:
For `uniqueId=1` pull a random set of 25 (`SAMPLE_A.SampleSz`) IPs (`SAMPLE_B.IP`) where `SAMPLE_A.uniqueId` is in the array of `SAMPLE_B.uniqueId`. Then iterate to the next `SAMPLE_A.uniqueId` and pull random 50450 ... etc.
Actual tables are a bit more complex, but I'm stuck here.

I was trying to write this for a singular record (and failed):

```
select i.ip, s.uniqueId
from SAMPLE_A s
join lateral (
   select distinct ip
   from SAMPLE_B i
   where s.uniqueId = any(i.uniqueId)
-- ORDER BY random()
   LIMIT s.SampleSz
   ) i on true
```

This throws an unmarshalling error. Even if it worked, it wouldn't solve my full issue, but I figured it was a first step.

***** UPDATE 1: Desired Result Set *****
I was going to do the result set as if the above tables are the entirety of the data set, but that really won't work (as it would show basically as if I just unnested the second table). So let's pretend that we are working (solely) with EVERY IP between 3.4.7.0 and 3.4.7.255; each has a record in SAMPLE_B with all 3 uniqueIds (1,2,3). For UniqueId 2, I would get the all 256 IPs (as it is less than the associated sample size (50,450). I would get 25 "random" records for 1. And for 3, I would get something like below (9 random records). Obviously, 2 will overlap completely (with 1&3); 1 & 3 could overlap each other on 0 to 9 records:

```
| IP       | uniqueId |
| -------- | -------- |
| 3.4.7.25 | 3        |
| 3.4.7.5  | 3        |
| 3.4.7.7  | 3        |
| 3.4.7.8  | 3        |
| 3.4.7.84 | 3        |
| 3.4.7.61 | 3        |
| 3.4.7.112| 3        |
| 3.4.7.125| 3        |
| 3.4.7.194| 3        |
| 3.4.7.207| 3        |
| 3.4.7.11 | 3        |
| 3.4.7.8  | 1        |
| 3.4.7.1  | 1        |
```

Comment: That query could be formatted just a *little* bit better.

Comment: Please update your question to show your desired result of the of the sample data. Post as text - **no images**.

Answer (score 0):

Your query works in my hands on Postgres 9.4.
The only true problem is `ORDER BY random()`, which cannot be combined with  `SELECT DISTINCT`, where `ORDER BY` only accepts items from the same `SELECT` list.

```sql
SELECT b.ip, a.uniqueid
FROM   sample_a a
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT DISTINCT b.ip
   FROM   sample_b b
   WHERE  b.uniqueid @> a.uniqueid  -- array operator
   -- ORDER BY random()  -- not possible like this!!
   LIMIT  s.samplesz
   ) b;
```

I switched to the array operator because that can be supported with an index. At least in Postgres. Not sure where Greenplum stands on GIN indexes. See:

- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns/29245753#29245753)

If you need a random sample, you need to do more. A simple solution would be a subquery like:

```sql
SELECT b.ip, a.uniqueid
FROM   sample_a a
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT *
   FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT b.ip
      FROM   sample_b b
      WHERE  b.uniqueid @> a.uniqueid  -- array operator
      ) b1
   ORDER  BY random()
   LIMIT  s.samplesz
   ) b;
```

But this performs poorly if there are *many* matches in `sample_b`. The best technique depends on cardinalities and your **exact** definition of "random". There are many shades of grey ...
Related:

- [Best way to select random rows PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql/8675160#8675160)

Comment: The issue is that there are over 2B potentially matching records in sample_b (which actually contains a lot more records that I am eliminating for other mismatches not shown). As far as my definition of "random", I understand that random is not truly random, but I guess I'm looking for results in no discernible order; so long as the code or existing data structure is not influencing the result set, I'll accept it as random.

Comment: It's an interesting problem. The update sheds some light, more is missing. The solution can be optimized (dramatically) depending on the exact, complete situation. Either way, that's "above the pay grade" of a question on SO. Sounds more like consulting work.