# Using LIKE with ANY(array)?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, sql-like

```
select sum(case when '%sys%' like any(series_arr)
                  or 'displays' = any(lob_arr)
                then revenue else 0 end) as sys_displ_revenue
from mytable
```

Basically, when I run this query, the term `'%sys%' like any(<array column>`) seems to get ignored, and only the 'displays' revenue is used.

How to solve this?

Comment: @mandy8055 `LIKE` *can* be used with `ANY()` without a problem. It's just that the pattern is it's right operand, and here it's flipped. [See this demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/BpH37dgb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. All PostgreSQL [pattern matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) operators accept the string as their left operand and the pattern as their right operand. Your code tries to do the opposite order.
2. As initially suggested by [@mandy8055](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19090048/mandy8055), you can [`unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#id-1.5.8.25.6.2.2.19.1.1.1) and use `like` with each element.
3. The `sum(case)` conditional aggregate construct can be replaced with a [`filter` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES).

[Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/2yOl4XRv)

```sql
select sum(revenue)filter(where exists(select from unnest(series_arr)_(e) 
                                       where e like '%sys%')
                          or 'displays' = any(lob_arr)) as sys_displ_revenue
from mytable
```

Comment: Yes, `FILTER` is almost always faster and more elegant than an aggregated `CASE` expression. Corner-case difference: returns `null` instead of `0` if none qualify.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LIKE` with the `ANY` construct. But the pattern goes to the right of the operand, and `LIKE` (or rather, it's internal implementation `~~`) has no [`COMMUTATOR`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xoper-optimization.html#XOPER-COMMUTATOR).

#### Custom operator

With the necessary privileges, you ***could*** create your own custom operator to make it work:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION reverse_like (text, text)
  RETURNS boolean
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE COST 10
RETURN $2 LIKE $1;

CREATE OPERATOR <~~ (
  FUNCTION = reverse_like
, LEFTARG  = text
, RIGHTARG = text
);
```

Then:

```
SELECT sum(CASE WHEN '%sys%' <~~ ANY (series_arr)
                  OR 'displays' = ANY (lob_arr) THEN revenue END) AS sys_displ_revenue
FROM   mytable;
```

I skipped `ELSE 0`. Without `ELSE`, SQL `CASE` defaults to `null`, and sum ignores null anyway. Only makes a difference if all rows evaluate to `null`, in which case you get null instead of 0, (and you might want to catch that with `COALESCE`).

Be aware that you can't get (direct) index support with the indexed column to the right of the operator. But that hardly matters for your query, which does a full sequential scan of the table anyway.

See:

- [Match string pattern to any array element](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/228262/3684)
- [PostgreSQL Operator Class for index support of custom operator](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/247085/3684)
- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns/29245753#29245753)

I am using minimal syntax for a "standard SQL" function, btw. See:

- [What does BEGIN ATOMIC mean in a PostgreSQL SQL function / procedure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/300512/3684)

#### Without custom operator

Barring that, a correlated subquery does the job:

```sql
SELECT sum(CASE WHEN (SELECT bool_or(s ~ 'sys') FROM unnest (series_arr) s)
                  OR 'displays' = ANY (lob_arr) THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) AS sys_displ_revenue
FROM   mytable t
```

Using the simpler regexp operator `~`, but all the same.

I would use the latter, unless you can put the custom operator to good use in more than just this query.